Proving that if $L^+$ is finite, then it is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ Analysis I, Terence Tao
The below result comes from Analysis I, 3rd edition, Terence Tao. I attempted to prove part (e) below (I added parts (b) and (c) as I use them in the proof):

Propsition 6.4.12. Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers, let $L^+$ be the limit superior of this sequence, and let $L^-$ be the limit inferior of this sequence (thus both $L^+$ and $L^-$ are extended real numbers).
(b) For every $x < L^+$, and every $N \geq m$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that $a_n > x$. Similarly, for every $y > L^-$, and every $N \geq m$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that $a_n < y$.
(c) We have $\inf(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty} \leq L^- \leq L^+ \leq \sup(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$.
(e) If $L^+$ is finite, then it is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$. Similarly, if $L^-$ is finite, then it is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$.


Here's my proof for $L^+$ (proof for $L^-$ should be similar):
Suppose $L^+$ is finite. We need to show that for every $\varepsilon >0$ and every $N \geq m$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that $|a_n - L^+|\leq \varepsilon$.
Since $L^+$ is finite, the expression $L^+ - \varepsilon$ is well-defined.  Moreover, for all $\varepsilon >0$, we have $L^+ - \varepsilon < L^+$. By (b), this implies that for all $N \geq m$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that $L^+ - \varepsilon < a_n$
We also have that $L^+ < L^+ + \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. By (c), we have that $L^- \leq L^+$, implying $L^- < L^+ + \varepsilon$. By (b), this implies that for all $N \geq m$, there exists an $n' \geq N$ such that $a_{n'} < L^+ + \varepsilon$.
Since the existence of such $n$ and $n'$ is true for every $N \geq m$, we can choose $a_n$ and $a_{n'}$ such that $a_n \leq a_{n'}$. Thus, we have that $L^+ - \varepsilon < a_n \leq a_{n'} < L^+ + \varepsilon$. This implies that $|a_n - L^+| \leq \varepsilon$, as was to be shown.

Question 1: Is my last paragraph a valid argument? What I mean is, can I really "choose" $a_n$ and $a_{n'}$ such that $a_n \leq a_{n'}$?
Question 2: Whether the answer to the above question is yes or no, is the rest of the proof valid? Or did I misstep anywhere?

There is not enough information in the last paragraph to let you choose such $a_n$ and $a_{n'}$. As far as I remember, proving this part (e) also requires part (a) of 6.4.12, not just part (b).

Q1: No. Q2: makes little sense imo.

@balddraz yes, I am aware of that proof. I just wanted to see if the above proof would work.

As mentioned in the comments, choosing such $a_n$ and $a_{n’}$ is undecidable given the information.
